# Integrable functions with uniformly bounded derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be in $L^{1}(R)$. Suppose $f$ is infinitely differentiable with uniformly bounded derivatives. Question: Is it true or false that the derivatives are also in $L^{1}(R)$.

My hunch is that this may be false but I have been unable to construct a counter example.

Thanks for you help.

Pronob

Answer (score 0):

How about
$$
f(x)=e^{-x^2}\sin\bigl(e^{x^2}\bigr)?
$$